# Is there a way to print html source without having it displayed in a window or tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, printing

So I have this situation:

I perform an ajax post to a controller action that returns me some complete html source (i.e. if the result was viewed in a browser and you right-clicked and selected view source, all of that is what gets returned).

Now I want to be able to print that html source as if was being displayed in a browser (i.e. not the markup but what a user would actually see if it was being displayed in a browser).

This must be done without opening a new tab or window or popup window. Is it possible? And if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about with a temporary, invisible iframe?

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentDocument.open();
iframe.contentDocument.write(html_source_here);
iframe.contentDocument.close();
iframe.contentWindow.print();
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it by creating a DIV and add the HTML by calling the [innerHTML](http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/Javascript/Javascript-DOM/Change-Div-InnerHTML/Default.aspx) function.

```
document.getElementById('yourNewDIV').innerHTML = htmlReceived;
```

Comment: Well that won't help with printing just the response page, as you'd be printing the parent page, with the response HTML inside a div. In addition, things in the parent page like styles and scripts could interfere with the div. An iframe is probably better for this.

Comment: Thanks, actually I downloaded some jquery that will work nicely with the "new div" idea and that will work with printing. This jquery has the function printElement() ... so you just say $("element").printElement() ...